# How to refactor AND and OR in a left outer join as hive doesn't support or in ON clause

Tags: sql, hive, left-join

I'm running a hive left outer join query which involves AND and OR in ON clause. Hive doesn't support OR in ON clause. How do I rewrite this to run in Hive? If UNION is one of the answer, please note that the version of hive I'm using doesn't support UNION. Supports UNION ALL only.

```
select 
*
from
a
left outer join b on a.a1=b.b1
left outer join c on c.c10=a.15 and (c.12=a.25 or c.13=a.25)
left outer join d on d.d1=a.a5
where
?
```

Comment: can you just move `(c.12=a.25 or c.13=a.25)` to where clause?

Comment: That was my first try. Didn't yield intended results. In fact no results. It works for inner join. Not for left outer

Answer (score 0):

You could combine `UNION ALL` with `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM (
  select *
  from a
  left outer join b on a.a1=b.b1
  left outer join c on c.c10=a.15 and c.12=a.25 
  left outer join d on d.d1=a.a5
  where ?
  UNION ALL
  select *
  from a
  left outer join b on a.a1=b.b1
  left outer join c on c.c10=a.15 and c.13=a.25
  left outer join d on d.d1=a.a5
  where ?
) s
```

Comment: Thanks @Lukasz Szozda. That was a quick turnaround. I tried this. However, hive was throwing an error for count (distinct *). Hence was stuck there. I wrapped the distinct again and took count. It works! Thanks very much. I hope the results are accurate. Data quality wise though count looks accurate.